# How to use the FingerPrint Sensor of my HP Envy-15 in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, fingerprint-reader

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 in my HP Envy-15 laptop which comes with a fingerprint sensor but isn't used by Ubuntu. Do I need to install drivers for it? Where can I find it?

The `lsusb` command yields this result:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 275d:0a29  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:0050 Validity Sensors, Inc. Swipe Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b40e Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HP Truevision HD camera
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`
```

which tells that my Validity Sensor device ID is `138a:0050`.

Comment: Did you try fprint from the Ubuntu Software repository?

Comment: No, what is that ?? No search results found on Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: I have a HP Envy 17t with a fingerprint sensor, and Mint 19, but lsusb does not show any sensor device, although there is something calledCheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) . Is there something that I need to run to recognise it?

Answer (score 2):

You can test it using the following steps:
Open a terminal and install [hw-probe](https://github.com/linuxhw/hw-probe): `sudo apt install hw-probe` then run `sudo -E hw-probe -all` to check the hardware. Open the file with gedit: `gedit /root/HW_PROBE/LATEST/hw.info/devices.json` and you'll probably find in the status field you get "Status" : "failed"
If so, take the first line of the fingerprint driver (will be of the format "usb:11aa-22bb")

go to https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?view=search and type the "22bb" part into the DeviceID field, check the results for your device and see what driver (if any) you need for it to work

Answer (score 0):

Click on the launcher Dash button, find the Software & Updates and launch it. At the bottom left of the window, click on the *Settings* button. Under the first tab, *Ubuntu Software*, make sure the *Community-maintained free and open-source software (universe)* is checked. The package list will update if a change was made, and you can then install the package `fprintd`. Or in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fprintd
```

Read the man page for instructions on running it.

```
man fprintd
```

The synopsis is:

```
fprintd-enroll [username]
fprintd-list username [usernames...]
fprintd-verify [-f finger] [usename]
fprintd-delete username [usernames...]
```

The first thing to do is enroll your username, for example:

```
fprintd-enroll -f right-index-finger myusername
```

There is another package with "fingerprint" in the name which is more GUI-related, but seems to have more problems than `fprintd`. Even `fprintd` has problems recognizing prints, and even if it does, you still have the issue of it not being able to open the keyring. So you will still need to type in the password to access that (like for email). Didn't save me any time, so I finally just removed it.

Comment: I installed it but nothing happened. How can I add a feaature that allows me to scan finger print during login and give access to my account. I think what you asked me to do was to install the driver for the sensor...

Comment: I have an Envy 17 with a fingerprint sensor on the right-hand side, but nothing shows up in lsusb. Apart from the root hub and Intel, the only entry is "Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink)". Is there a way to probe the hardware (I don't have a manifest)?

Comment: fprintd-enroll says "list_devices failed: No devices available"